# chrome not workign .offset().top

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, offset

Not working in chrome.... element.offset().top
**any suggestions**

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $(".scroll-box").scroll(function(){
    $('#document_activity .doc-draft.item.parent').each(function(i) {
      $movingLableTop = [];
      $movingLableHeight = [];
      $fixedLableTop = $('#fixed_version').find('.version').offset().top;
      $movingLableTop.push($(this).offset().top);
      $movingLableHeight.push($(this).height());
      if ($fixedLableTop > ($movingLableTop + $movingLableHeight)){
        $('#fixed_version').find('.version').html($(this).find('.version').html());
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Lot of people mentioned that chrome not get right value for offset()

Comment: What isn't working?  What is it doing that you not expect?  Who are the "lot of people" you refer to?  What versions of chrome, HTML, JQuery, etc are you using?

Comment: chrome version Version 21.0.1180.57 jquery v1.7.2

$(this).offset().top nothing working in chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Thx its is fixed are working now

instead of this 
$(this).offset().top

by using

$(this).position().top